# sequential access to object with multiple thread using synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an exercise in which I have to increment a counter, squaring the counter, and wait 500 milliseconds before repeating the operation.
I'm forced to use two threads class and the synchronized modifier. 
It's possible? Can someone help me? 
This is my code:

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;   

public class Sync2Thread{

     private static Counter c;

     static class Counter{
         private int count;  

         public synchronized int getCount() { 
             return count;
         }

         public synchronized void incrCount() { 
             count++; 
             System.out.println("+1 => counter= "+count);
             try {
                 sleep(500);
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
             }
         }
     }

     public static void main (String[] args){
         c = new Counter();

         Thread t = new Thread(new IncrCounter());
         t.start(); 
         Thread t2 = new Thread(new Square());        
         t2.start();
     }

     /**
       * Thread that increment the counter
       */
     static  class IncrCounter extends Thread {

          public void run(){
             for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
             {  
                 System.out.println("Current Counter = "+c.getCount());
                 c.incrCount();  
             }
         }
     }

      /**
       * Thread that calculates the square
       */
     static class Square extends Thread {

         public void run(){
             for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
             {   
                 int x = c.getCount();
                 System.out.println(x + " squared =>"+ x*x + "\n");    
                 yield();
             }
         } 
     } 

 }
```

My results are similar to:

```
Current Counter= 0
+1 => counter= 1
Current Counter= 1
+1 =>  counter= 2
1 squared =>1 
2 squared =>4 
2 squared =>4 
2 squared =>4 
2 squared =>4 
.....
```

but it must be:

```
Current Counter= 0
+1 => counter= 1
1 squared =>1

Current Counter= 1
+1 => counter= 2
2 squared =>4

Current Counter= 2
+1 => 3
3 squared =>9
```

thank you so much

Comment: Hi ! You can use a lock before increment and release it after square

Comment: The `Thread.yield()` method does not do what you seem to think it does.  It would do something kind of close to what you think it does *IF* your code was running in a cooperative multitasking environment on a single-CPU machine, but on a modern OS running on a modern desktop or laptop system, the best way to think about `yield()` is to imagine it doing nothing at all.

Comment: A tip (not a solution) : don't sleep while holding a lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user Doubi says, it works well with methods wait() and notify().

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep; 

public class Sync2Thread{

 private static Counter c;

 static class Counter{
     private int count;  

     public int getCount() { 
         return count;
     }

     public void incrCount() { 
         count++; 
         System.out.println("+1 => counter= "+count); 
     }
 }

 public static void main (String[] args){
     c = new Counter();

     Thread t = new Thread(new IncrCounter());
     t.start(); 
     Thread t2 = new Thread(new Square());        
     t2.start();
 }

 /**
   * Thread that increment the counter
   */
 static  class IncrCounter extends Thread {

      public void run(){
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {  
            synchronized (c) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("Thread1 - Current Counter = "+c.getCount());
                    System.out.println("Thread1 - Waiting to get notified after squared");
                    // This waits for the other thread perform exponentiation
                    c.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {  }
                System.out.println("Thread1 - Waiter thread got notified, let's raise!"); 
                // As soon as the other thread has raised to a power, it increments the counter.
                c.incrCount(); 
                c.notifyAll();
            }  
         }
         System.out.println("Thread1 end___");
     }
 }

  /**
   * Thread that calculates the square
   */
 static class Square extends Thread {

     public void run(){
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {  
            synchronized (c) {

                int x = c.getCount();
                System.out.println("Thread2 - "+ x + " squared =>"+ x*x);    
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Thread2 - Sqared done, send notify\n");
                    c.notifyAll();
                    c.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {   }
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Thread2 end___");
     } 
 }
```

}

output example:

```
Thread1 - Current Counter = 0
Thread1 - Waiting to get notified after squared
Thread2 - 0 squared =>0
Thread2 - Sqared done, send notify

Thread1 - Waiter thread got notified, let's raise!
+1 => counter= 1
Thread1 - Current Counter = 1
Thread1 - Waiting to get notified after squared
Thread2 - 1 squared =>1
Thread2 - Sqared done, send notify

Thread1 - Waiter thread got notified, let's raise!
+1 => counter= 2
Thread1 - Current Counter = 2
Thread1 - Waiting to get notified after squared
Thread2 - 2 squared =>4
Thread2 - Sqared done, send notify

Thread1 - Waiter thread got notified, let's raise!
+1 => counter= 3
Thread1 - Current Counter = 3
Thread1 - Waiting to get notified after squared
Thread2 - 3 squared =>9
Thread2 - Sqared done, send notify

Thread1 - Waiter thread got notified, let's raise!
+1 => counter= 4
Thread1 - Current Counter = 4
Thread1 - Waiting to get notified after squared
Thread2 - 4 squared =>16
Thread2 - Sqared done, send notify

Thread1 - Waiter thread got notified, let's raise!
+1 => counter= 5
Thread1 end___
Thread2 end___
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue lies in the method yield(). It only says "Hey, I've done my job. If some other thread wants, it can go to running state now." So it puts the thread into runnable state and then looks, which threads are in runnable state and can get to running state. If the two lines before yield() are faster than the 500ms the other thread is waiting, the square-thread will be the only one in runnable state. So it will immediately get to work again.

A solution would either be to let the two threads wait for each other with wait() and notify(), or to use sleep instead of yield.

Comment: Yield() doesn't say, "I've done my job."  It says, "I've still got more work I can do, but *IF* you want to give me a break, then this would be a good time."

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

Remove `synchronizaed` method and use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in place of `int count`.

> An int value that may be updated atomically. See the java.util.concurrent.atomic package specification for description of the properties of atomic variables. An AtomicInteger is used in applications such as atomically incremented counters,

You can't achieve your expected result with current code unless you increment and square in same thread Or use two different Counter instances for these two threads.

Example code: ( Still with side effects due to counter access in different threads)

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep; 
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class Sync2Thread{
     private static Counter c;
     static class Counter{
         private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);  
         public int getCount() { 
             return count.get();
         }
         public  void incrCount() { 
             count.incrementAndGet();
             System.out.println("+1 => counter= "+getCount());
             try {
                 sleep(500);
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
             }
         }
     }
     public static void main (String[] args){
         c = new Counter();
         Thread t = new Thread(new IncrCounter());
         t.start(); 
         Thread t2 = new Thread(new Square());        
         t2.start();
     }

     /**
       * Thread that increment the counter
       */
     static  class IncrCounter extends Thread {
          public void run(){
             for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
             {  
                 System.out.println("Current Counter = "+c.getCount());
                 c.incrCount();  
             }
         }
     }
      /**
       * Thread that calculates the square
       */
     static class Square extends Thread {
         public void run(){
             for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
             {   
                 int x = c.getCount();
                 System.out.println(x + " squared =>"+ x*x + "\n");  
                 c.incrCount();  

             }
         } 
     } 
 }
```

output:

```
Current Counter = 0
0 squared =>0

+1 => counter= 1
+1 => counter= 2
Current Counter = 2
+1 => counter= 3
3 squared =>9

+1 => counter= 4
Current Counter = 4
+1 => counter= 5
5 squared =>25

+1 => counter= 6
Current Counter = 6
6 squared =>36

+1 => counter= 7
+1 => counter= 8
8 squared =>64

Current Counter = 8
+1 => counter= 9
+1 => counter= 10
10 squared =>100

+1 => counter= 11
Current Counter = 10
+1 => counter= 12
Current Counter = 12
+1 => counter= 13
13 squared =>169

+1 => counter= 14
```

Comment: The question states he is forced to use synchronized (probably because it's what they're learning about)

Comment: The OP's problem is a variation on a fairly common intro-to-threads exercise.  The student is supposed to figure out how to make the two threads to take turns.  In its more common form, the assignment is to print all the integers from 1 to N, in ascending order, with one thread producing all of the odd numbers and the other producing all of the even numbers.  IMO, it's a Bad Example because, while the student might learn something about _how_ to make threads do tricks; it gives them a completely wrong idea about _why_ to use threads.

Comment: Yes. I have provided output with side effects.